# How to know if we're in a react-native context?

Tags: react-native

I have an npm library that is made to work in a browser and in a Node environment.

When used in a node environment it checks if the `require` function exists, and requires modules such as `fs`.

```
var fs = null;
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  fs = require('fs');
}
```

Such modules do not exist in react native and therefore when I use this library in react native, I get an error.

What's the best way to know if we're in a react native context vs node ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68509272/12610347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, @borislemke's answer did not work, it appears that you cannot conditionalize `require`. I think it's `babel` that constructs the tree of dependencies without taking into account the conditions.

I finally moved the `require` into a file that gets added with `grunt`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this without you setting it somewhere explicitly. React native does have `require` but not `fs`. this is probably why you get the error. `global` is also available on both, so it might be an option to store an `isReact` variable in the `global` Object.

`global.isReact = true`. `isReact` will be available throughout your app. Many say it is not wise to use `global` variables but in this case it can be an exception.

You also create an `env.js` file in your root dir where you set a `isReact` variable and `require` that file whenever you need to determine whether you're running in React Native or Node.