# Conditional imports in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I'm having a bit of trouble getting conditional imports working in react native.

I have some files that are used in a react web app and in react native.

What I'd like:

```
if(process.env.REACT_PLATFORM === 'WEB') {
    import('some_file').then(({someFunc})=> someFunc())
}
```

Because 'some_file' imports `react_router`.

However, this import is still happening, and the RN metro bundler throws

`UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module 'react-router' from 'some_file'.`

Even If I replace it as:

```
if(false) {
    import('some_file').then(({someFunc})=> someFunc())
}
```

It still trys to load `some_file`. Is there anyway to only import/require this file if a condition is met?

Cheers!

EDIT: 
Things I've tried:

- Require instead of import.
- https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/

Answer (score 12):

[Platform specific imports](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#native-specific-extensions-ie-sharing-code-with-nodejs-and-web);

You can place the import in a component with the `native.js` extension and it will only be bundled for mobile (ios/android). e.g. MyComponent.native.js Then you have a component for web with the same name but the `.js` extension. e.g. My Component.js

When you import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent', the correct one will be imported and the other ignored.

Answer (score 9):

After a bit of searching, in turns out dynamic imports can be a bit of a pain.

This is the solution I came up with, I've tried it in node.

```javascript
const MODULE_NAME = <CONDITION> ? require(MODULE_A) : require(MODULE_B);
```

Alternatively, I guess you could do something like this;

```
const MODULE_TO_IMPORT = 'MODULE_IMPORT_STRING';
const MODULE_NAME = import(MODULE_TO_IMPORT).then(({someFunc}) => someFunc());
```

But the problem is that these *require* a module to be imported either way.

Comment: `let module; if(true) { module = require(MODULE); }` ? We did similar with dev tools modules in our project.

Comment: Note: if you want the default export, you should access the 'default' key returned from the require function:
`const MODULE_NAME = <CONDITION> ? require(MODULE_A).default : require(MODULE_B).default;`

Comment: @jaquinocode how can I get the default export but also any other export in the module?

Answer (score 3):

For React-navive-web we can use manage code for platform-specific that will manage in Mobile App and Web Also

> Web-specific code # Minor platform differences can use the Platform
> module.

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  height: (Platform.OS === 'web') ? 200 : 100,
});
```

> For example, with the following files in your project:

```
MyComponent.android.js
MyComponent.ios.js
MyComponent.web.js
And the following import:
```

import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
React Native will automatically import the correct variant for each specific target platform.

Comment: Yeaaahyy, thanks so much! That solved it for me in the end :)

Answer (score 3):

[Platform specific imports](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#native-specific-extensions-ie-sharing-code-with-nodejs-and-web) are nice but won't help you on the web.

`react-native` section in `package.json` is your friend:

```
"react-native": {
  "module1": false,
  "module2": "module3"
}
```

with this setup

```js
// module1
export const x = 1

// module2
export const x = 2

// module3
export const x = 3

// will result in
import {x} from 'module1'
console.log( x === undefined ) // in the react-native environment
console.log( x === 1 ) // in the browser

import {x} from 'module2'
console.log( x === 3 ) // in the react-native environment
console.log( x === 2 ) // in the browser

import {x} from 'module3'
console.log( x === 3 ) // in the react-native environment
console.log( x === 3 ) // in the browser
```

The docs can be found [here](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec). It's for the `browser` section, but the `react-native` section works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a problem where the project I am working on is using `react-native-tvos` and I tried to add `react-native-ad-manager` as a dependency but it doesn't support tvOS so I wanted to dynamically import the ad manager dependency for non tvOS platforms. I was able to get it to work like such:

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

const NullComponent = (props: any) => null;

const AdComponent = () => {
  const [Banner, setBanner] = React.useState(() => NullComponent);

  if (!Platform.isTV) {
    import('react-native-ad-manager')
      .then(({Banner: AdBanner}) => {
        setBanner(() => AdBanner);
      })
  }

  return (
    <Banner />
  )
}
```