# Can you conditionally import files in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import, modular

Situation: I'm working on a react native project with different versions for the same app. To do this I'm using app flavors for android and for iOS I will be using build targets. I've already made a native android module that can return the android build flavor that is being used. My goal is to be able to import a different React component to display for each flavor.

Problem: My original idea was to conditionally import the React Native component to display for each flavor, but I've come to understand that conditional imports aren't a thing in JavaScript and they have to be at the top level scope. Is there a way to tackle this problem without importing every file for every build? (I want to avoid making the binary larger by importing components that are only being used in other flavors of the app).

What I want to do:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

var appFlavor;

NativeModules.RNVariantsLib.getBuildFlavor((err ,flavor) => {
  console.log('flavor ' + flavor);
  appFlavor = flavor;
});

if(appFlavor == 'flavorA'){
  import Component from './a';
}
if(appFlavor == 'flavorB'){
  import Component from './b';
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: it would be nice if you select one of the answers if it solved your problem

Comment: @RafaelCavalcante https://stackoverflow.com/a/68509272/12610347

Answer (score 1):

You could try with require

```
let Component = null;
if(appFlavor == 'flavorA'){
  Component = require('./a');
}
if(appFlavor == 'flavorB'){
  Component = require('./b');
}

export default Component;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution from [Conditional imports in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340877/conditional-imports-in-react-native)

`const MODULE_NAME = <CONDITION> ? require(MODULE_A) : require(MODULE_B);`