# What's a clean way to handle architectural differences between React Native and React Native Web codebases?

Tags: react-native, express, expo, react-native-web

I’m working on an application with two very different incarnations:

- a React Native app that includes certain processing services because **offline use is mandatory**
- a React Native Web app in which these services are accessed via an Express API for better security and performance

For the RN app, my code is something like this:

```
import summarize from '../services/summarize';
const response = summarize({ factors })
```

For the RNW app, it's:

```
const response = axios.put(`${ROOT_URL}/summarize`, { factors });
```

What's a clean way to handle such different code?  I'm currently commenting/uncommenting one version or the other depending on my build target, but there must be better ways.

Comment: `Platform.OS === 'web'`  https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code

Comment: Well, in the RNW version I won't even import summarize, so I'll get an error if there's any code that references it.

Comment: Well, then you can use platform specific file extension (like .web.js) or conditional imports with require or import() syntax https://stackoverflow.com/a/50341763/5793132

Comment: I didn't know about platform-specific file extensions.  That'll work great for me.  Feel free to make that the answer and I'll accept it.