# Nativewind not working in both android and web expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, tailwind-css, nativewind

I Set up a project in expo Nativewind for both web and android platforms. But getting errors in the CSS file.
But project is running in web.

Android Bundling failed 2084ms
Unable to resolve "./styles.css" from "App.tsx"

styles.css

```
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

App.tsx-

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import './styles.css';
export default function App() {
  const variable: string = 'variable';
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-gray-600">
      <Text className="text-red-200">
        Open up App.js to start working on your app!
      </Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic import [Conditional imports in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340877/conditional-imports-in-react-native)

You must create

```
App.js # picked up by webpack, Rollup or any other Web bundler
App.native.js
```

with the `import './styles.css';`in App.js

In my case, to avoid to duplicate code in `App.js` and `App.native.js`, I have create a `Main.tsx` file to share code

1. `App.native.js`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Main from './src/Main'

const App = () => {
    return <Main />
}

export default App
```

2. `App.js`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Main from './src/Main'

// import in expo web
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
    return <Main />
}

export default App
```